# Is a scan with an antivirus software enough?

Tags: security, anti-virus

I have read that if your computer gets hacked you can't be really sure that you have a clean system even if you manage to stop the hacker and the best thing to do is to reinstall your OS. Do you agree with this?

What about different types of file including audio,video,pdf and executable files. If I move them to an external drive is it enough to scan them with an antivirus? If the antivirus says that it did not find any threats, can I trust it? Is it correct at least 99%?

Comment: After being locked out of my files with ransomware - I now run Windows 10 with DEEP FREEZE installed. Every time I reboot - my C drive (and D if you also want to freeze it) is RESTORED to its original state and all changes that have been made are removed.

Now I can install, test and customize ANY software from ANY source without any worry about malware or ransomware. I just reboot to remove all changes to my C drive (and D if desired) and return to a clean installation.

By the way, you can temporarily DISABLE Deep Freeze so you can install updates or install safe software.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes scan with an antivirus is not enough. Antivirus software is good for preventing the viruses and other malware from getting into your system and from operating there, but once they are in, sometimes it is almost impossible to clean them out. More to say, there are a lot of types of adware that are not detectable by any kind of antivirus software. Moving your files to external drive won't help either, if you are doing it using your current OS. Definitely the best solution is to back-up all the files you need and do a CLEAN OS installation after formatting your HDD or SSD. You can also try using virtual machine or sandbox software, in case you often deal with dangerous files.